# Check if an array only contains one key/value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$foo = array('one');
$foofoo = array('onekey' => 'onevalue');
```

How do you check if an array contains only one key?

Comment: there's nothing more to expound there @zerkms

Comment: it is just an accident that someone could guess right what you need. Generally the question needs to be formed better

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`count()` will tell you how many elements are in an array

```
if (count($foo) === 1) {
    echo 'This array contains one value';
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. I was thinking of rather a function, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just needed this :) I was thinking way too difficult ;)

Comment: Nice and smooth!